Getting sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError when there clearly are the foreign key relationships explicitly declared between objects and ARRAY datatype
I am working on a project where I need to create a SQLModel ORM for a PostgreSQL database. The database has multiple schemas and I attempted to create separate model files for each schema.
There are two specific issues I am running into:

No Foreign Key error when I think I modeled it "correctly" to the best of my understanding
Unable to generate pydantic-core schema for ARRAY datatype

For the first issue of No Foreign Key:
There are foreign key relationships between two objects within same schema, i.e., in my try within same file (e.g., Entity and OrgType objects in rcrootschema.py below), as well as foreign key relationships between objects across schema / files (e.g., Entity in rcrootschema.py and Address in supplychainschema.py)
Here are my files to replicate the issue which is running on Python 3.11.8 in PyCharm CE and PostgreSQL 14.9 (Homebrew) on MacOS.
# main.py
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Session, select
from connection import engine

import models.rcrootschema as dbs, models.supplychainschema as scs

SQLModel.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    print(select(dbs.SubscriberType))
    print(select(dbs.OrgType))
    print(select(dbs.Entity))
    print(select(dbs.EntityRelatioship))
    print(select(scs.LocationType))
    print(select(scs.Address))

# connection.py
# included here for referential completeness only; feel free to skip this file
from __future__ import annotations
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, create_engine, Session
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from typing import Optional
from decouple import config

try:
    dbcon = URL.create(drivername=config('dbdriver'),
                       username=config('dbuser'),
                       password=config('dbpassword'),
                       host=config('dbhost'),
                       database=config('database'),
                       port=config('dbport')
                       )
except:
    print('Database connection is unsuccessful')

engine = create_engine(dbcon)
SessionFactory = Session(engine)

DATABASE_URL: Optional[str] = None
SECRET_KEY: Optional[str] = config("secret")


def sess_db():
    db = SessionFactory()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


# rcrootschema.py

from typing import List, Optional, TYPE_CHECKING
from decouple import config

from sqlmodel import Field, MetaData, Relationship, ARRAY
from sqlmodel import SQLModel

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from supplychainschema import Address


dbschema = config('dbschema')


# Schema: resichain
class SubscriberType(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'subscriber_types'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': dbschema}

    type: str = Field(default=None, nullable=False, primary_key=True)

    entities: List['Entity'] = Relationship(back_populates='subscribertype')


class OrgType(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'org_types'

    type: str = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

    entities: List['Entity'] = Relationship(back_populates='orgtype')


class Entity(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "entities"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": dbschema}

    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

    name: str = Field(nullable=False, index=True)
    subscriber_type: Optional[str] = Field(nullable=False, default='regular',
                                           foreign_key=dbschema + '.subscriber_types.type')
    is_active: bool = Field(nullable=False, default=True)
    org_type: str = Field(nullable=False, default='subscriber',
                          foreign_key=dbschema + '.org_types.type')

#    nickname: Optional[ARRAY(str)]       << Refer to this declaration for the second issue

    # Objects that Entity refers to
    subscribertype: Optional['SubscriberType'] = Relationship(back_populates='entities')
    orgtype: 'OrgType' = Relationship(back_populates='entities')

    # Objects that references Entity
    parents: List['EntityRelatioship'] = Relationship(back_populates='parentEntity')
    children: List['EntityRelatioship'] = Relationship(back_populates='childEntity')

    entity_addresses: List['Address'] = Relationship(back_populates="bizEntity")


class EntityRelatioship(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'entity_relationships'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': dbschema}

    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

    parent_entity_id: int = Field(nullable=False, foreign_key=dbschema + '.entities.id', index=True)
    child_entity_id: int = Field(nullable=False, foreign_key=dbschema + 'entities.id', index=True)
    relationship: str = Field(nullable=False, foreign_key=dbschema + '.org_types.type', index=True)
    is_active: bool
    child_entity_code: Optional[str]

    # Objects that EntityRelationship refers to
    parentEntity: 'Entity' = Relationship(back_populates='parents')
    childEntity: 'Entity' = Relationship(back_populates='children')


# supplychainschema.py

from typing import List, Optional, TYPE_CHECKING
from decouple import config

from sqlmodel import Field, MetaData, Relationship
from sqlmodel import SQLModel

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from rcrootschema import Entity


dbschema = config('dbschema')
scschema = config('scschema')

# Schema: supplychain

class LocationType(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'location_types'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': scschema}

    type: str = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

    location_addresses: List['Address'] = Relationship(back_populates='locationtype')

class Address(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': scschema}

    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

    address_string: str  # full entered address as one string
    lat: Optional[float]
    lon:Optional[float]
    location_type: str = Field(nullable=False, default='hq', foreign_key=scschema + '.location_types.type', index=True)
    entity_id: Optional[int] = Field(foreign_key=dbschema + '.entities.id', index=True)

    # Objects that Address refers to
    locationtype: 'LocationType' = Relationship(back_populates='location_addresses')
    bizEntity: Optional['Entity'] = Relationship(back_populates='entity_addresses',
                                                 sa_relationship_kwargs=dict(foreign_keys='[Address.entity_id]')
                                                 )

The error Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2423, in _determine_joins
    self.primaryjoin = join_condition(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 123, in join_condition
    return Join._join_condition(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 1355, in _join_condition
    raise exc.NoForeignKeysError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'org_types' and 'entities'.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tapas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(select(dbs.SubscriberType))
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 318, in __str__
    return str(self.compile())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 307, in compile
    return self._compiler(dialect, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 315, in _compiler
    return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 1429, in __init__
    Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 870, in __init__
    self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 915, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 141, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)  # type: ignore  # noqa: E501
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 4674, in visit_select
    compile_state = select_stmt._compile_state_factory(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 684, in create_for_statement
    return klass.create_for_statement(statement, compiler, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 1091, in create_for_statement
    _QueryEntity.to_compile_state(
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 2546, in to_compile_state
    _MapperEntity(
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/context.py", line 2626, in __init__
    entity._post_inspect
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1253, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2711, in _post_inspect
    self._check_configure()
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2388, in _check_configure
    _configure_registries({self.registry}, cascade=True)
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 4203, in _configure_registries
    _do_configure_registries(registries, cascade)
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 4244, in _do_configure_registries
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2405, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 584, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1644, in do_init
    self._setup_join_conditions()
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1884, in _setup_join_conditions
    self._join_condition = jc = JoinCondition(
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2310, in __init__
    self._determine_joins()
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2444, in _determine_joins
    raise sa_exc.NoForeignKeysError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship OrgType.entities - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

Process finished with exit code 1

As for the second issue of modeling an ARRAY datatype:
I have an Entity attribute defined as text[] datatype in Postgresql. I tried to model it as nickname: Optional[ARRAY(str)] in sqlmodel and to make it recognizable imported ARRAY from sqlmodel. Unfortunately I get the following pydantic error when running it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tapas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import models.rcrootschema as dbs, models.supplychainschema as scs
  File "/Users/tapas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/models/rcrootschema.py", line 34, in <module>
    class Entity(SQLModel, table=True):
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlmodel/main.py", line 451, in __new__
    new_cls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dict_used, **config_kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_model_construction.py", line 202, in __new__
    complete_model_class(
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_model_construction.py", line 539, in complete_model_class
    schema = cls.__get_pydantic_core_schema__(cls, handler)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 607, in __get_pydantic_core_schema__
    return handler(source)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_schema_generation_shared.py", line 82, in __call__
    schema = self._handler(source_type)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 499, in generate_schema
    schema = self._generate_schema_inner(obj)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 750, in _generate_schema_inner
    return self._model_schema(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 577, in _model_schema
    {k: self._generate_md_field_schema(k, v, decorators) for k, v in fields.items()},
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 577, in <dictcomp>
    {k: self._generate_md_field_schema(k, v, decorators) for k, v in fields.items()},
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 913, in _generate_md_field_schema
    common_field = self._common_field_schema(name, field_info, decorators)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 1078, in _common_field_schema
    schema = self._apply_annotations(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 1817, in _apply_annotations
    schema = get_inner_schema(source_type)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_schema_generation_shared.py", line 82, in __call__
    schema = self._handler(source_type)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 1798, in inner_handler
    schema = self._generate_schema_inner(obj)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 755, in _generate_schema_inner
    return self.match_type(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 837, in match_type
    return self._match_generic_type(obj, origin)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 861, in _match_generic_type
    return self._union_schema(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 1149, in _union_schema
    choices.append(self.generate_schema(arg))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 499, in generate_schema
    schema = self._generate_schema_inner(obj)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 755, in _generate_schema_inner
    return self.match_type(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 841, in match_type
    return self._unknown_type_schema(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tapas/Anaconda/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_generate_schema.py", line 402, in _unknown_type_schema
    raise PydanticSchemaGenerationError(
pydantic.errors.PydanticSchemaGenerationError: Unable to generate pydantic-core schema for ARRAY(''). Set `arbitrary_types_allowed=True` in the model_config to ignore this error or implement `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` on your type to fully support it.

If you got this error by calling handler(<some type>) within `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` then you likely need to call `handler.generate_schema(<some type>)` since we do not call `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` on `<some type>` otherwise to avoid infinite recursion.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/u/schema-for-unknown-type

Process finished with exit code 1


For the NoForeignKeyError I am at a loss since it seems to me I have defined it as I understood how it should be. Still I tried to add sa_relationship_kwargs argument in the Relationship() to explicitly reference the foreign key. It did not resolve the issue. Problem here is I am not able to understand why it is throwing this error to attempt any resolution or workaround.
For the ARRAY() modeling, I followed the pydantic resolution advice to add this Type in the pydantic CoreSchema like below so it may generate the model. I added this in rcrootschema.py before the classes. One option is to take the ARRAY datatype field to a new object and create a 1:m relationship between the two. But I think that defeats the purpose and ease.
from pydantic import BaseModel, BaseConfig, CoreSchema

class MyModel(BaseModel):
   array: ARRAY('')

   def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(self):
       return CoreSchema(type='array', items=CoreSchema(type='string'))


But it complains about not finding CoreSchema
